# How to check if the mouse cursor is inside the polygon?

Tags: python, gpu

How to check if the mouse cursor is inside the polygon?

[image]

```
import bpy, bgl,  gpu
from bpy.types import Operator
from math import radians, cos, sin
from gpu_extras.batch import batch_for_shader

class XX_OT_test(Operator):
    bl_label = 'Test'
    bl_idname = 'xx.test'
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    def inside_polygon(self, position, points):
        ''' Check if the mouse cursor is inside the polygon

        position (2D Vector) - Position of the mouse cursor.
        points (list of 2D Vectors) - List of points that make up the polygon.
        return (bool) - True if the mouse cursor is inside the polygon.
        '''
        # code here

    def overlay(self, context, event):
        coords = []
        position = (200, 200)
        radius = 10

        for angle in range(0, 361, 5):
            radian = radians(angle)
            x = position[0] + radius * cos(radian)
            y = position[1] + radius * sin(radian)
            coords.append((x,y))

        bgl.glEnable(bgl.GL_BLEND)
        bgl.glEnable(bgl.GL_LINE_SMOOTH)
        shader = gpu.shader.from_builtin('2D_UNIFORM_COLOR')
        batch = batch_for_shader(shader, 'TRI_FAN', {'pos': coords})
        shader.bind()
        shader.uniform_float("color", bpy.context.preferences.themes['Default'].user_interface.axis_z[:] + (0.8, ))
        batch.draw(shader)

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        args = (context, event)
        self._2d_handle = bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(self.overlay, args, 'WINDOW', 'POST_PIXEL')
        context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def modal(self, context, event):
        context.area.tag_redraw()

        if event.type in {'ESC', 'RIGHTMOUSE'}:
            bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_remove(self._2d_handle, 'WINDOW')
            return {'CANCELLED'}
        elif event.type in {'MIDDLEMOUSE'}:
            return {'PASS_THROUGH'}

        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}
    
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(XX_OT_test)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(XX_OT_test)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Do you mean inside a polygon in screen space ?

Comment: Yes, whenever the mouse cursor is inside the polygon in screen space